# Can I put an app bought with an old ID on my iPad with its new ID?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id

I bought the app for my old iPod Touch and used the second of two IDs I have...now I use another ID.  They're both mine.  I bought some apps with this alternative ID, can I put those apps on my new iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

1. Open Settings.app
2. Scroll down and tap on "iTunes & App Stores"
3. Tap on "Apple ID: [yourappleid@example.com]
4. Tap Sign out
5. After signing out of your "new" Apple ID sign in with your old one and download the app.